# Calling mulitple user selections from dropdown form in javascript function

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I am teaching myself how to code. I can't figure out how to take multiple values from an HTML drop down form and directly input them into a predefined function via javascript.(Form attributes?)

```
<form action="mywebsite.html">
<p> Month </p>
<select name="Bmonth">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
</select>

<p> Day </p>
<select name="Bdom">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<p> Year </p>
<select name="Byear">
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2015</option>
    <option value="2013">1988</option>
</select></form>

<script>
function DOB(Bmonth, Bdom, Byear) {
var z=Byear-Bmonth*Bdom;
    return window.alert("Your number is " +z);
}
DOB(Bmonth, Bdom, Byear);
</script>
```

I simply want to take the three values that the user provides and enter them into the function DOB(Bmonth, Bdom, Byear); If I run the code like this it says "Bmonth is undefined."

Comment: where is your JS function? Please include that also

Comment: I don't see why it matters. The function is rather long, but it runs clean.

Comment: I will put a simplified version in for the general idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a javascript framework or library that will make your life easier. For instance, with jQuery you would adapt your code like so:

```
<form action="mywebsite.html">
<p> Month </p>
<select name="Bmonth">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
</select>

<p> Day </p>
<select name="Bdom">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<p> Year </p>
<select name="Byear">
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2015</option>
    <option value="2013">1988</option>
</select></form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function DOB(Bmonth, Bdom, Byear) {
    var z=Byear-Bmonth*Bdom;
    return window.alert("Your number is " +z);
}
DOB(
    $('[name="Bmonth"]').val(),
    $('[name="Bdom"]').val(), 
    $('[name="Byear"]').val()
);
</script>
```

And with some further tweakings (adding a button to trigger DOB function and using ids instead of name): http://jsfiddle.net/neewonej/

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much. That really works. Can you point me in the right direction so that I can better understand the code so as to properly be able to utilize jquery? Recommended references?

Comment: I would go with official jQuery's websites. They have a learning center (http://learn.jquery.com/) and an API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ which is the one resource I use most for jQuery. Things I've used in my examples are the id selector (http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and attribute equality selector (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), the val function (http://api.jquery.com/val/) and click binder function (http://api.jquery.com/click/). Glad I could help :)

Comment: Also, don't forget to mark your preferred answer as accepted and upvote the ones you appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all change name="" to id="" to make simpler with javascript selection. Which looks like this:

```
<form action="mywebsite.html">
<p> Month </p>
<select id="Bmonth">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
</select>

<p> Day </p>
<select id="Bdom">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<p> Year </p>
<select id="Byear">
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2015</option>
    <option value="2013">1988</option>
</select></form>
```

You need to get the handle of the select box to tempElement variable using tempElement = document.getElementById("Bmonth"). Then get the selected index using tempElement.selectedIndex and make this index to retrieve value from tempElement.options. Use tempElement.options[tempElement.selectedIndex].value to get the value equivalent that user selects otherwise use tempElement.options[tempElement.selectedIndex].text to get the selected text.

Here is the working javascript code:

```
function DOB(Bmonth, Bdom, Byear) {
    var z=Byear-Bmonth*Bdom;
    return window.alert("Your number is " +z);
}
var tempElement = document.getElementById("Bmonth");
Bmonth = tempElement.options[tempElement.selectedIndex].value;

tempElement = document.getElementById("Bdom");
Bdom = tempElement.options[tempElement.selectedIndex].value;

tempElement = document.getElementById("Byear");
Byear = tempElement.options[tempElement.selectedIndex].value;

DOB(Bmonth, Bdom, Byear);
```

Thanks